# How to use a TFLite model on a javascript program?

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-native, tensorflow, tensorflow-lite

I have a program I'm working on that uses JavaScript (or typescript and react native, more specifically) to classify images taken by the camera or selected from the device's gallery. I have a TFLite model ready to use, but I'm not sure how to get those images to work with the model.

I think my biggest issue is I don't fully understand how the code I'm using interacts with the different modules I've been trying.

Here's what I have so far.

```
export default class CameraPage extends React.Component {
  camera = null;

    state = {
        captures: [],
        capturing: null,
        hasCameraPermission: null,
        cameraType: Camera.Constants.Type.back,
        flashMode: Camera.Constants.FlashMode.off,
    };

    setFlashMode = (flashMode) => this.setState({ flashMode });
    setCameraType = (cameraType) => this.setState({ cameraType });
    handleCaptureIn = () => this.setState({ capturing: true });

    handleCaptureOut = () => {
        if (this.state.capturing)
            this.camera.stopRecording();
    };

    handleShortCapture = async () => {
        const photoData = await this.camera.takePictureAsync();
        this.setState({ capturing: false, captures: [photoData, ...this.state.captures] })
    };

    handleLongCapture = async () => {
        const videoData = await this.camera.recordAsync();
        this.setState({ capturing: false, captures: [videoData, ...this.state.captures] });
    };

    async componentDidMount() {
        const camera = await Permissions.askAsync(Permissions.CAMERA);
        const audio = await Permissions.askAsync(Permissions.AUDIO_RECORDING);
        const hasCameraPermission = (camera.status === 'granted' && audio.status === 'granted');

        this.setState({ hasCameraPermission });
    };

    render() {
        const { hasCameraPermission, flashMode, cameraType, capturing, captures } = this.state;

        if (hasCameraPermission === null) {
            return <View />;
        } else if (hasCameraPermission === false) {
            return <Text>Access to camera has been denied.</Text>;
        }

        return (
            <React.Fragment>
                <View>
                    <Camera
                        type={cameraType}
                        flashMode={flashMode}
                        style={styles.preview}
                        ref={camera => this.camera = camera}
                    />
                </View>

                {captures.length > 0 && <Gallery captures={captures}/>}

                <Toolbar 
                    capturing={capturing}
                    flashMode={flashMode}
                    cameraType={cameraType}
                    setFlashMode={this.setFlashMode}
                    setCameraType={this.setCameraType}
                    onCaptureIn={this.handleCaptureIn}
                    onCaptureOut={this.handleCaptureOut}
                    onLongCapture={this.handleLongCapture}
                    onShortCapture={this.handleShortCapture}
                />
            </React.Fragment>
        );
    };
}
```

My first issue is I need to know where the images are going and how to reference them. Second, how to use those images in a TFLite model. And third how to do the same thing pulling the images instead from the gallery.

After all that, I need to see about taking optimal images from a short video to use in the model, but I'll tackle that in another ask if I can't figure it out.

Thank you.